# ulimit -n not changing - values limits.conf has no effect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, pam, ulimit

I am trying to raise the open file descriptor maximum for all users on an ubuntu machine.

This question is somewhat of a follow up to this question.

[open file descriptor limits.conf setting isn't read by ulimit even when pam_limits.so is required](https://serverfault.com/questions/235356/open-file-descriptor-limits-conf-setting-isnt-read-by-ulimit-even-when-pam-limi)

except that i've added the required "root" entries in limits.conf

Here are the entries

```
*               soft    nofile           100000
*               hard    nofile           100000
root            soft    nofile           100000
root            hard    nofile           100000
```

Lines related to `pam_limits.so` have been un-commented in all relevant files in /etc/pam.d/ and `fs.file-max` has been set correctly in /etc/sysctl.conf

However, I still see

```
abc@machine-2:/etc/pam.d$ ulimit -n
1024
```

after reboot.

What could be the problem?

My default shell is /bin/sh and i can't use chsh to change my default shell since the my user on the machine is authenticated via some distributed authentication scheme.

Comment: strace -o loglimit su - abc and after that egrep "(limit|open)" loglimit, maybe your pam configuration are wrong

Comment: @c4f4t0r, the - option to su only causes a new login when it's the last argument. I only know this because I was just reading that man page. Also, as a detail, a regular user cannot strace an suid root binary.

Comment: as root you need to use the command strace -o loglimit su - abc

Comment: sorry for spam but i have this kind of issue http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200310/how-to-run-script-with-a-clean-login-shell

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem, but with SSH logins only.  Local logins (via console) respected the `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

As it turned out, when you set:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, then sshd forks an unprivileged child to set up the account's env.  Because this child is unprivileged, then pam_limits.so setting upper limits had no effect.

As soon as I set

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and bounced the SSH service, then the limits.conf file were respected with SSH logins.

Comment: In my case I changed sshd-config to `UsePAM yes`.  (+1 for pointing me to sshd-config)

Answer (score 6):

On Redhat server logged as root

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
user01  -       nofile  2048
```

strace command logged as root

```
strace -o loglimit su - user01
```

with other shell open loglimit

```
grep "limit" loglimit
open("/lib64/security/pam_limits.so", O_RDONLY) = 6
 ..........
 ..........
 open("/etc/security/limits.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3
 read(3, "# /etc/security/limits.conf\n#\n#E"..., 4096) = 1823
 open("/etc/security/limits.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
 setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=2*1024, rlim_max=2*1024}) = 0
```

In this way I know that, pam_limits was loaded and limits.conf was readed, if your pam_limits was loaded but you still see other values using ulimit -n, check your shell profile as @etherfish told

Comment: I got the error: `prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=10000000, rlim_max=10000000}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)`.  This was because I had set the limit too high.  Fixed by reducing the limit.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the ulimit is being applied by a /etc/profile or a ~/.bashrc. The fact that your system has a complicated pam, I would confirm that something isn't going awry.

I'd also confirm that there isn't an errant file in /etc/security/limits.d/ being parsed as mentioned in pam_limits(8).

I'd add debug parameter to the session required pam_limits.conf line and then watch /var/log/auth.log as you log in.

If your soft limit is 1024, whats your hard limit?

su should get you a fresh, new log in with su using the -l argument.

su -l -s /bin/bash

Good Luck.

Comment: my hard limit is 4096 i.e `ulimit -Hn`

Answer (score 4):

I was with a issue like this, here what I did.

The strace command will print all interactions the process are doing with external libraries, so with it we can see if our config is loaded or not.

So, i do, like suggested above:

```
root:/etc/pam.d$ strace -o ~/loglimit su - glaudiston
glaudiston:~$ exit
logout
root:/etc/pam.d$ cat ~/loglimit | grep limits.conf
```

In my issue, the strace log (strace -o log su - username) does not have any instance of limits text, so the file limits.conf was NOT loaded.

First I make sure the pam_limits.so looks for /etc/security/limits.conf

```
root:/etc/pam.d$ strings /lib/security/pam_limits.so | grep limits.conf
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

So, I make sure that the module pam_limits.so is loaded in auth operation in files located at /etc/pam.d ... for example, in /etc/pam.d/su, I added:

```
session   required    pam_limits.so
```

Now, I can make a "su" to my user and the limits will be loaded. You can redo the strace step to make it sure.

My linux is a LFS, so is my fault the absense of pam_limits.so in /etc/pam.d files. In other distros I don't think to be this exact issue.

But hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Centos 6.10) strace showed that after limit was set from **/etc/security/limits.conf** later on in the login process it was reset from **/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf** for all non-root users:

```
*          soft    nproc     1024
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```